# User identifiable info online

Tags: php

What is the info available online to identify a user. I looked at PHP and started a list:

1. IP ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
2. Browser ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
3. Browser Language (?)

what else?

I am trying to create a temp user signature (in addition to cookies, if those are cleaned).
Say we get two users: A and B. There can be a chance they come from the same IP, but perhaps their browser environment is slightly different.

Is the following coming from user's browser too?

HTTP_ACCEPT = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET = ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING

Comment: not  question. just look in the php doc

Comment: There's a lot of server-related info, I'm just interested to what's pertaining to user. And it does not have to be just PHP related. Is there a way to check if user is accepting cookies, for example? What about geo location or is it tied to IP?

Comment: anything pertaining to client info is mostly on the client side, they can send fake info to the server if they want. you can **never** trust the client to send u correct info

Comment: What else what? You already have his IP. Any other source of *specific* identification has to come from you (like you setting cookies or session data etc)

Comment: I am not thinking of a savvy user. Clearly there's no 100% way to fool-proof this. I do use cookies, but if someone cleaned them, I need to have some sort of ability to potentially spot the same user. I am not even worried about AOL users that use dynamic IPs. In my opinion, if you're still on AOL, you probably don't clean cookies very often (mildly put).

Comment: I think you're looking for the wrong solution. From your example, what if A and B have the same browsers? Or if A decided to switch browsers? You can't collect unique information from a broad field like browser-info; you have to make this unique info.

Answer (score 1):

```
Browser Language = $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]
```

For others;

```
foreach($_SERVER as $a=>$b) {
  print $a . " = " . $b . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: AHHHH that prints out some stuff that you might not want the client to know!

Comment: But for negotiate client info, use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-negotiate-language.php

Comment: @Neal: Ahh it's true. I forgot to add that; " Hi attacker! Here is $_SERVER info. I hope I helped you."

Answer (score 0):

As far as user identifiable, that's pretty much everything. You can look at the $_SERVER array in the php.net documentation to learn how to get these variables:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

If you wanted some Geo-location based off the IP address, php has a library for it:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 0):

1. From which site you come ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])

Comment: I am trying to create a temp user signature (in addition to cookies, if those are cleaned)... Referrer can be different for the same user.